# Make div be on the same line as text, where to put display:inline-block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### The context :

Im using a on/off switch button, where i would like the help-text to be on the same line as the switch.

It look's like this right now:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I've googled that i can [use this](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbuC/1/) is my div-style:

```
display:inline-block;
```

#### My code :

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    /* bottom = footer height */
    padding: 25px;
}
    
footer {
    background-color: #5B8CA8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.upp {
    background-color: #5B8CA8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 39px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px; 
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 23px;
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 11px; 
    color: white; 
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "PÅ";
    padding-left: 7px;
    background-color: #5B8CA8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "AV";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 4px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 28px;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<p>
Help Text
</p>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitchT1" unchecked onclick="javascript:toggle1();">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitchT1">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

#### My question :

Where should i put `display:inline-block;` in my div-style?

Comment: Your help text should be in a `span`, not a `p`. Then it will naturally be an inline element

Comment: You need this: `p, div { display:inline-block;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both `display : inline-block;` & `vertical-align : middle;` on both your `p` element and your `.onoffswitch` class. That should produce the desired effect!

A demo :

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    /* bottom = footer height */
    padding: 25px;
}
    
p {
    display : inline-block;
    vertical-align : middle;
}
    
footer {
    background-color: #5B8CA8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.upp {
    background-color: #5B8CA8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 39px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px; 
    display : inline-block;
    vertical-align : middle;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 23px;
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 11px; 
    color: white; 
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "PÅ";
    padding-left: 7px;
    background-color: #5B8CA8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "AV";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 4px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 28px;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<p>
Help Text
</p>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitchT1" unchecked onclick="javascript:toggle1();">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitchT1">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Try [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wr5p4xf7/11/).

---

### Note :

It's a VERY BAD idea to set `display : inline-block;` & `vertical-align : middle;` for all p elements.

It's a MUCH, MUCH better idea to add a class to your p element, like this :

```
<p class="help">
Help Text
</p>
```

Now, you can set the styles for that element like this :

```
p.help {
    display : inline-block;
    vertical-align : middle;
}
```

This prevents these styles from being applies to all p elements!

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wr5p4xf7/12/).

Answer (score 2):

Both p and div should have inline-block style.

Of course, in real project I'd not put style attribute - use css classes instead.

```
<p style="display: inline-block">
Help Text
</p>
<div class="onoffswitch" style="display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitchT1" unchecked onclick="javascript:toggle1();">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitchT1">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sergei, Could you give me an example?